# Integrating weather information in iphone

Tags: iphone

Can anyone tell me the steps to integrate weather information into my iPhone App. I found some API's are there, but didn't found steps for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: NOAA REST interface,yahoo etc,but many of them are not free.can you please tell me the steps.

Comment: Yahoo has one, but it is a RSS feed instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://www.weather.com/services/xmloap.html

Comment: Thankyou.But this source is html.Is there any site that uses XML?can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

use google weather in php

see the link http://komunitasweb.com/2009/09/showing-the-weather-with-php-and-google-weather-api/

to iphone see old question in so :

<strike>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305127/free-weather-api</strike>