# Including Weather Information, iPhone App, Weather API

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, json, weather-api

I am not sure if what I want to do is possible, as i am fairly new to this.  I have signed up for a Free API account with WorldWeatherOnline.com which allows usage of free and commercial use.

What I want to do is have the 3 days weather displayed for a specific location when a user visits a certain ViewController of my app.  I'm not looking to ask them for their location via GPS, just display a set locations current weather.

I can generate a Request URL and output in XML format or JSON, but have no idea how to implement them into my app (if it is possible?)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for the [Best Weather API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507441/best-weather-apis),

Read the blog tutorial with sample code for

[Adding Local Weather Conditions To Your App (Part 2/2: Accessing Google’s XML Weather API)](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/09/29/adding-local-weather-conditions-to-your-app-part-22-accessing-googles-xml-weather-api/)

[Integrating weather information in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634271/integrating-weather-information-in-iphone)