# Google API to Get Weather Information

Tags: ios, iphone, google-weather-api

I need to fetch the weather information based on the user's current location. Please provide me the Google API to get the weather info.

I am using http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Mumbai, but Google is returning some error:

> **We're sorry...**
>
> ... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now.
>
> See Google Help for more information.

When I looked it up on Google, I found out that Google API is down.

Please guide me which one is the latest Google API to get the weather info.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Weather API gone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145820/google-weather-api-gone)

Answer (score 6):

Google terminate Weather API permanently...

Alternatively you can use:

1. [WunderGround API](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/)
2. [Yahoo API](http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/)

Comment: Note- Yahoo API just changed theirs to require oAuth

Comment: This isn't true anymore. You can use Google's awareness api to get weather info based off of current location.

Comment: Important EOL Notice: As of Thursday, Jan. 3, 2019, the weather.yahooapis.com and query.yahooapis.com for Yahoo Weather API will be retired.
To continue using our free Yahoo Weather APIs, use https://weather-ydn-yql.media.yahoo.com/forecastrss. Follow below instructions to get credentials and onboard to this free Yahoo Weather API service.

Comment: Google's awareness api getWeather got deprecated in 2020. https://developers.google.com/awareness/overview

Answer (score 4):

Hi arundhati have you Google it? i just searching in google and found best answer From :-

[Including Weather Information, iPhone App, Weather API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029607/including-weather-information-iphone-app-weather-api)

Check for the [Best Weather API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507441/best-weather-apis),

Read the blog tutorial with sample code for

[Adding Local Weather Conditions To Your App (Part 2/2: Accessing Google’s XML Weather API)](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/09/29/adding-local-weather-conditions-to-your-app-part-22-accessing-googles-xml-weather-api/)

[Integrating weather information in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634271/integrating-weather-information-in-iphone)

Hope its helps you :)

**This is a Demo of Weather API iphone**

https://github.com/elc/ICB_LocalWeather

[image]

**[Weather Underground API](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api)**

Example: http://api.wunderground.com/auto/wui/geo/GeoLookupXML/index.xml?query=90210

Comment: Thanks nithin will check it.do u have any idea on underground weather api.

Comment: As of Oct-2018 Weather Underground have stopped issuing API access to new users as they are scaling down their operations

Answer (score 3):

Google Weather API is down. Check out the following alternatives:

[Open Weather Map](http://openweathermap.org)

[National Digital Forecast](http://graphical.weather.gov/)

[Weather.com](http://weather.com)

I've been using the first link. Its free like Open Street Maps.

EDIT:

Here's the basic code to get the JSON:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://openweathermap.org/data/2.1/find/city?lat=32.85190&lon=57.65878&cnt=1&type=JSON"]];

if (jsonData) {

    id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error is %@", [error localizedDescription]);

        // Handle Error and return
        return;

    }

    NSArray *keys = [jsonObjects allKeys];
    // values in foreach loopDic]
    for (NSString *key in keys) {
        NSLog(@"%@ is %@",key, [jsonObjects objectForKey:key]);
    }


} else {
    // Handle Error
}
```

Add that to the `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Plenty of sources suggest the same. Here's a random link http://thenextweb.com/google/2012/08/28/did-google-just-quietly-kill-private-weather-api/

Comment: i have created app id in open weather site now i m not getting how to use that appid ,i mean append that aphid to give url.

Comment: Here's an example http://openweathermap.org/data/2.1/find/city?lat=5.85190&lon=60.65878&cnt=1&type=JSON

Answer (score 3):

The best weather API is [here](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/).

Sample JSON response from them is as below:

```
{
  "response": {
  "version": "0.1",
  "termsofService": "http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
  "features": {
  "conditions": 1
  }
  },
  "current_observation": {
  "image": {
  "url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png",
  "title": "Weather Underground",
  "link": "http://www.wunderground.com"
  },
  "display_location": {
  "full": "San Francisco, CA",
  "city": "San Francisco",
  "state": "CA",
  "state_name": "California",
  "country": "US",
  "country_iso3166": "US",
  "zip": "94101",
  "latitude": "37.77500916",
  "longitude": "-122.41825867",
  "elevation": "47.00000000"
  },
  "observation_location": {
  "full": "SOMA - Near Van Ness, San Francisco, California",
  "city": "SOMA - Near Van Ness, San Francisco",
  "state": "California",
  "country": "US",
  "country_iso3166": "US",
  "latitude": "37.773285",
  "longitude": "-122.417725",
  "elevation": "49 ft"
  },
  "estimated": {},
  "station_id": "KCASANFR58",
  "observation_time": "Last Updated on June 27, 5:27 PM PDT",
  "observation_time_rfc822": "Wed, 27 Jun 2012 17:27:13 -0700",
  "observation_epoch": "1340843233",
  "local_time_rfc822": "Wed, 27 Jun 2012 17:27:14 -0700",
  "local_epoch": "1340843234",
  "local_tz_short": "PDT",
  "local_tz_long": "America/Los_Angeles",
  "local_tz_offset": "-0700",
  "weather": "Partly Cloudy",
  "temperature_string": "66.3 F (19.1 C)",
  "temp_f": 66.3,
  "temp_c": 19.1,
  "relative_humidity": "65%",
  "wind_string": "From the NNW at 22.0 MPH Gusting to 28.0 MPH",
  "wind_dir": "NNW",
  "wind_degrees": 346,
  "wind_mph": 22.0,
  "wind_gust_mph": "28.0",
  "wind_kph": 35.4,
  "wind_gust_kph": "45.1",
  "pressure_mb": "1013",
  "pressure_in": "29.93",
  "pressure_trend": "+",
  "dewpoint_string": "54 F (12 C)",
  "dewpoint_f": 54,
  "dewpoint_c": 12,
  "heat_index_string": "NA",
  "heat_index_f": "NA",
  "heat_index_c": "NA",
  "windchill_string": "NA",
  "windchill_f": "NA",
  "windchill_c": "NA",
  "feelslike_string": "66.3 F (19.1 C)",
  "feelslike_f": "66.3",
  "feelslike_c": "19.1",
  "visibility_mi": "10.0",
  "visibility_km": "16.1",
  "solarradiation": "",
  "UV": "5",
  "precip_1hr_string": "0.00 in ( 0 mm)",
  "precip_1hr_in": "0.00",
  "precip_1hr_metric": " 0",
  "precip_today_string": "0.00 in (0 mm)",
  "precip_today_in": "0.00",
  "precip_today_metric": "0",
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "forecast_url": "http://www.wunderground.com/US/CA/San_Francisco.html",
  "history_url": "http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KCASANFR58/2012/6/27/DailyHistory.html",
  "ob_url": "http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?query=37.773285,-122.417725"
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think "http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api" the best? I searching for an weather API, provides credible and reliable data. It's OK to pay for the credibility and reliability.  Or is there any forum that I can discuss and find more leads of the credibility and reliability. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Google Weather APIs are not supported anymore.
You can use other weather APIs that are available.

Here are a few you can choose from.

1. [Ambee](https://www.getambee.com/api/weather)
2. [Darksky](https://darksky.net/dev)
3. [OWM](https://openweathermap.org/api)